# Angular test using $httpBackend fails with "400 thrown" error

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

For hours I've been trying to test my NewPostController with $httpBackend. The problem is whenever I set non-2xx status code in the response, the test fails.

NewPostController has the following method:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  var newPost = $scope.newPost;
    PostService.insertPost(newPost).then(function (post) {
      $location.path("/my-posts");
    }, function (status) {
        $scope.form.$setPristine();
        $scope.error = status;
    });
};
```

I have a problem testing the failure path:

```
it(...) {
  ...
  $scope.post.text = "";
  $httpBackend.expectPOST("/create-post", {"post":$scope.post}).respond(400);
  $scope.submit();
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect($scope.error).toBeDefined();

  $scope.post.text = "This is a valid text.";
  $httpBackend.expectPOST("/create-post", {"post": $scope.post}).respond(200);
  $scope.submit();
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect($location.path()).toBe("/my-posts");
});
```

The test fails with a message "400 thrown" (no callstack). I tried to change the order of subtests, use whenPOST instead of expectPOST and combine the methods as they do in Angular docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) but without success.

Please help.

EDIT:

Now when I look at PostService, it makes sense where the "400 thrown" comes from but I expected the error to be handled by angular. I threw it because of the section "Handling problems in nested service calls" of [this article](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/). It is supposed to be a shorter version of deferred.resolve/reject mechanism.

```
this.insertPost = function (newPost) {
  return $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "/create-post",
    data: {
      post: newPost
    }
  }).then(function (res) {
      return (res.data);
  }, function (res) {
      throw res.status;
  });
};
```

Comment: Post the complete output from karma. And post the code of PostService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed strange, and is perhaps something the angular team didn't consider.

When a promise is rejected by throwing (as you're doing), the angular [$exceptionHandler service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler) is called with the thrown exception. By default, this service just logs the exception in the browser console.

But when using ngMocks, [this service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$exceptionHandler) is replaced by a mock implementation that can either log or rethrow the exception. The default mode is to rethrow, in order to make a test fail when an exception is thrown.

My advice would be to avoid using throw to simply reject a promise, and thus replace

```
function (res) {
  throw res.status;
}
```

by

```
function (res) {
  return $q.reject(res.status);
}
```

But if you really want to keep using throw, you can also configure the mock exceptionHandler to log instead of rethrowing:

```
beforeEach(module(function($exceptionHandlerProvider) {
  $exceptionHandlerProvider.mode('log');
}));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried both solutions and they work. Are you more inclined to use $q.reject? I have no preference.

Comment: Yes. I have the feeling that throw should be used to signal an error (bug) rather than an expected condition. The fact that it doesn't play well with unit tests is also a sign that $q.reject() should be used instead. I also fear that configuring the exceptionHandler to log might make your tests fragile, and maybe succeed when they shouldn't.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks once again :)